# Error while compiling cm13 (6.0.1)

Tags: android, c++, cyanogenmod

Hi i am trying to compile cm13 for my old device GT-i8552 which runs msm7x27 basically and here is error. 
http://pastebin.com/raw/KwV9gwzC

and here is source of display-caf which i am using as base 
https://github.com/CM13-Y300/android_hardware_qcom_display-caf/tree/cm-13.0/libgralloc

any help is really appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Please copy the error and, if possible, the code into this question. People who might be able to help do not like to jump to outside webpages just because you did not take the time to copy these things  into your question. You should edit your question.

Comment: I hope you don't expect people to read all the code on that github page. Your errors indicate you forgot to link in a library or libraries containing the missing referenced functions. You should be able to find out where they are

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by removing ccache .

Comment: Wow, a reply after 18 months!